# Book with super powered kids with electrical powers

Tags: story-identification, powers

I’m trying to figure out the name of the book series with kids who have electrical superpowers.

They were all  in the same hospital when something short circuited in the wiring and it caused all of the babies to gain super powers which allowed them to all have some sort of control with electricity (neurons, electrical power, etc.). The main character thought he was the only one... until he found another girl who could control minds using electrical currents in the brain. They find more kids at a facility... that’s all I remember.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like *[Michael Vey: The Prisoner of Cell 25](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451656505)*, by Richard Paul Evans.

[image: Book Cover - Michael Vey: the Prisoner of Cell 25]

From Amazon:

> To everyone at Meridian High School, fourteen-year-old Michael Vey is nothing special, just the kid who has Tourette’s syndrome. But in truth, Michael is extremely special—he has electric powers. Michael thinks he is unique until he discovers that a cheerleader named Taylor has the same mysterious powers. With the help of Michael’s friend, Ostin, the three of them set out to discover how Michael and Taylor ended up with their abilities, and their investigation soon brings them to the attention of a powerful group who wants to control the electric teens—and through them, the world.

Answer (score -1):

The book is *Michael Vey and the Prisoner of Cell 25*.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! You may not have noticed, but there is already an answer for this question which suggests the same book. Your answer could still be useful if you [edit] it to include details about these books which match the ones given in the question.

Comment: This has already been provided as an answer, and with more detail.